# FireDAC SQLite Standard Encryption question

Tags: sqlite, delphi, firedac

If I declare and create some SQLite database inside FDConnectionDefs.ini as follows

```
[SQLITESAMPLE]
Database=sample.sdb
Password=masterkey
LockingMode=Normal
SharedCache=false;
DriverID=SQLite
```

it should be encrypted with `aes-256` as standard settings. `FDSQLiteSecurity1.CheckEncryption` is returning `aes-256`

Later, if I add the param `Encrypt=aes-256` to that definition my apps still work correctly.

But RAD Studio Data Explorer and FireDAC Explorer will only work with a setting 
`Encrypt=No`(with `aes-256` I get some corrupt datafile message from these two apps).

If I define the `Encrypt=aes-256` param from the beginning all apps do work correct.

Maybe there is some other encryption mode standard defined, if I do not declare encryption mode from the beginning? I wonder about this.

Comment: Jens have you looked at the SQLite Encryption sample project?
C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\Samples\Object Pascal\Database\FireDAC\Samples\DBMS Specific\SQLite\Encryption\SQLite_Encrypt.dproj

Answer (score 2):

The SQLite3 DB file is either encrypted, or not, from the beginning.

You will have to maunally backup the file from one encrypted state to another.

There is no "standard" free encryption on SQLite3.
Only a few variants:

- FireDAC encryption
- Closed Source [SQLite Encryption Extension](https://www.sqlite.org/see/doc/release/www/readme.wiki)
- [SQLite-Crypt](https://sqlite-crypt.com) commercial
- [SQLCipher](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/)
- [WXSQLite3 variant](https://utelle.github.io/wxsqlite3/docs/html/index.html)
- [DISQLite3](https://www.yunqa.de/delphi/products/sqlite3/index) commercial for Delphi
- [SynSQLite3](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2018/03/12/New-AES-based-SQLite3-encryption) Delphi/FPC Open Source
- and probably others... all incompatible!

Comment: I'm only talking about the fireDAC encryption and I have read at documentation, that aes-256 mode is automatically assigned, if no Encryption parameter is assigned, but a password is set and I can confirm it for my own app, but not for the two above mentioned. In principle it is no problem to assign the param from the beginning, I only try to understand it, because it is not logically ....and I'm worry it is not real encrypted, if only the password is assigned